# XAML link to section of window

Tags: wpf, xaml

In XAML how can I set a hyperlink to take the user to a particular section of my window. Like how you can with anchor tags in HTML. Basically we want the user to be able to click on an error in a list of errors and the link will take them to that area.

Comment: How is that area defined? Is it a specific control? A specific row in a grid? Something else?

Comment: The properties that could have errors are defined as a label and textbox/combobox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAML Hyperlink NavigateUri could work with a bit of code behind, i.e.

```
<Window x:Class="fwAnchorInWindow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxName" Text="Enter Name"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxNumber" Text="Enter Number"/>
        <TextBlock>
          <Hyperlink NavigateUri="TextBoxName" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
              There is a name error.
          </Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
namespace fwAnchorInWindow
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is Hyperlink)
            {
                string controlName = ((Hyperlink)sender).NavigateUri.ToString();
                IInputElement control = (IInputElement)this.FindName(controlName);
                Keyboard.Focus(control);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FindName is only one way to find a child control.  There are also other ways per this post: [WPF ways to find controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls).

It is also important to note that WPF distinguishes between Logical Focus and Keybaord Focus: [Mark Smith's It's Bascially Focus](http://julmar.com/blog/mark/?p=52).  In the code above having keyboard focus automatically indicates logical focus.